# Android menu's icon doesn't become visible on Tablet

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

Hi, Everyone, this is my code. The menu works perfectly on my phone (Android 2.3). But on my tablet (Android 4.0) it doesn't display the icon. The menu works fine. Could someone help me? Why does this happen? I'm using `Theme_Black_NoTitleBar` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
public final class IntentsDemoActivity extends Activity implements
        OnItemClickListener {

    public static final int ABOUT = 0;
    public static final int INFO = 1;
    public static final int WEBSITE = 2;

    // This is the value of Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY for API level 11 and above.
    private static final String EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY = "android.intent.extra.LOCAL_ONLY";
    private static final String VIDEO_ID = "-Uwjt32NvVA";
    private static final String PLAYLIST_ID = "PLF3DFB800F05F551A";
    private static final String USER_ID = "Google";
    private static final int SELECT_VIDEO_REQUEST = 1000;

    private List<DemoListViewItem> intentItems;

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add(0, ABOUT, 0, "About").setIcon(R.drawable.about);
        menu.add(0, INFO, 0, "Info").setIcon(R.drawable.info);
        menu.add(0, WEBSITE, 0, "Website").setIcon(R.drawable.website);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case ABOUT:
            Toast.makeText(IntentsDemoActivity.this, "About", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/about);
            Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
            startActivity(it);
            return true;

            case PAGE:
            Toast.makeText(IntentsDemoActivity.this, "Info", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/info");
            Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
            startActivity(it);
            return true;
           case WEBSITE:
          Toast.makeText(IntentsDemoActivity.this, "Webiste", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          Uri uri1 = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/");
            Intent it1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri1);
            startActivity(it1);
          return true;

          }
          return false;
      }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intents_demo);

        intentItems = new ArrayList<DemoListViewItem>();
        intentItems.add(new IntentItem("X", IntentType.X));
        intentItems.add(new IntentItem("Play Video", IntentType.PLAY_VIDEO));
        intentItems.add(new IntentItem("Open Playlist",
                IntentType.OPEN_PLAYLIST));
        intentItems.add(new IntentItem("Play Playlist",
                IntentType.PLAY_PLAYLIST));
        intentItems.add(new IntentItem("Open User", IntentType.OPEN_USER));
        intentItems.add(new IntentItem("Open Search Results",
                IntentType.OPEN_SEARCH));
        intentItems
                .add(new IntentItem("Upload Video", IntentType.UPLOAD_VIDEO));

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.intent_list);
        DemoArrayAdapter adapter = new DemoArrayAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_item, intentItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        TextView youTubeVersionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_version_text);
        String version = YouTubeIntents.getInstalledYouTubeVersionName(this);
        if (version != null) {
            String text = String.format(
                    getString(R.string.youtube_currently_installed), version);
            youTubeVersionText.setText(text);
        } else {
            youTubeVersionText
                    .setText(getString(R.string.youtube_not_installed));
        }
    }

    public boolean isIntentTypeEnabled(IntentType type) {
        switch (type) {
        case PLAY_VIDEO:
            return YouTubeIntents.canResolvePlayVideoIntent(this);
        case OPEN_PLAYLIST:
            return YouTubeIntents.canResolveOpenPlaylistIntent(this);
        case PLAY_PLAYLIST:
            return YouTubeIntents.canResolvePlayPlaylistIntent(this);
        case OPEN_SEARCH:
            return YouTubeIntents.canResolveSearchIntent(this);
        case OPEN_USER:
            return YouTubeIntents.canResolveUserIntent(this);
        case UPLOAD_VIDEO:
            return YouTubeIntents.canResolveUploadIntent(this);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        IntentItem clickedIntentItem = (IntentItem) intentItems.get(position);

        Intent intent;
        switch (clickedIntentItem.type) {
        case X:
            // This will load a picker view in the users' gallery.
            // The upload activity is started in the function onActivityResult.
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, null).setType("video/*");
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
            startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_VIDEO_REQUEST);
            break;

        case PLAY_VIDEO:
            intent = YouTubeIntents.createPlayVideoIntentWithOptions(this,
                    VIDEO_ID, true, false);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case OPEN_PLAYLIST:
            intent = YouTubeIntents.createOpenPlaylistIntent(this, PLAYLIST_ID);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case PLAY_PLAYLIST:
            intent = YouTubeIntents.createPlayPlaylistIntent(this, PLAYLIST_ID);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case OPEN_SEARCH:
            intent = YouTubeIntents.createSearchIntent(this, USER_ID);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case OPEN_USER:
            intent = YouTubeIntents.createUserIntent(this, USER_ID);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case UPLOAD_VIDEO:
            // This will load a picker view in the users' gallery.
            // The upload activity is started in the function onActivityResult.
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, null).setType("video/*");
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
            startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_VIDEO_REQUEST);
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent returnedIntent) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
            case SELECT_VIDEO_REQUEST:
                Intent intent = YouTubeIntents.createUploadIntent(this,
                        returnedIntent.getData());
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, returnedIntent);
    }

    private enum IntentType {
        X, PLAY_VIDEO, OPEN_PLAYLIST, PLAY_PLAYLIST, OPEN_USER, OPEN_SEARCH, UPLOAD_VIDEO;
    }

    private final class IntentItem implements DemoListViewItem {

        public final String title;
        public final IntentType type;

        public IntentItem(String title, IntentType type) {
            this.title = title;
            this.type = type;
        }

        @Override
        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return isIntentTypeEnabled(type);
        }

        @Override
        public String getDisabledText() {
            return getString(R.string.intent_disabled);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have pasted the same icons in the all Drawable folders i.e, ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and especially xhdpi in case of tablets.

Post the menu.xml file if you have all versions of icons in corresponding folders.

Answer (score 0):

> But on my tablet (Android 4.0) it doesn't display the icon.

It is not supposed to display the icon, if it is in the overflow menu in your action bar. The overflow menu is text-only.

Answer (score 0):

Drawble-ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi folders must hold their own files so put your icon with same name to different folders. I think your code is not wrong there is only flea error. Also your layout files must in different drawable folders with same name if you are creating different visual..